# Which is best way passing variable long data one page to another page in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on travel portal. In this listing api I'm getting Flight_Key and Search_Key.
so for the next api call I need flight_key and search_key. But I want to know which is best way for pass this two key listing page checkout page. I can not pass in url because key length is very big.

Which method or logic I do I have to use to pass variables from the listing page to the checkout page?

I am developing this in CodeIgniter 3.0 in PHP.

Sample for Flight Key and Search Key

```
"Search_Key": "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",

"Flight_Key": "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",
```

I am calling third party API for listing. Every flight has a different flight_key and search key is common. Please provide example for more clarification.

Sample response

```
{
    "Response_Header": {
        "Error_Code": "0000",
        "Error_Desc": "SUCCESS",
        "Error_InnerException": "",
        "Request_Id": "5500887959052",
        "Status_Id": "11"
    },
    "Search_Key": "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",
    "TripDetails": [
        {
            "Flights": [
                {
                    
                    
                   
                    "Flight_Key": "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",
                    
                    
                    "TravelDate": "09/25/2022"
                },
                {
                                        
                    "Flight_Key": "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",
                    
                    
                    "TravelDate": "09/25/2022"
                },
            ]
    }
```

Comment: use session/DB/Cookies

Comment: if this two keys are same for all of the user or can be reused by the user in the future then it's better to store them on DB and it will save lots of lines of code and time